# How Can I Merge a Separate Edge Loop into a Face?

Tags: modeling

I have an edge loop that is part of the same object as the box shown below. I would like to merge it into the face that it is on top of to make the geometry all one.

[image]

Comment: I would suggest using the knife project feature.

Comment: For creating the rounded square you see, I created a circle and delete it some verticles, but the circle isn't connected to the main mesh, even if it's in the same object, i'm stuck at this point :/

Comment: See my answer. It has more details.

Comment: i'm sorry but cegaton saved my life this time :/ (and i know how to use the knife) thank you for the effort you made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two edge loops have the same number of vertices you can use bridge edge loops.

Delete the face that connects the outside loop.

Select all and do: Bridge Edge Loops

[image]

Comment: FYI, the Bridge tool doesn't require an equal number of verts on both edges.

Comment: Nice! But I tried your tip, but the result was awful, double face overlapping... etc... so I made it myself face by face and the result is more than satisfying! http://i.imgur.com/6IjMro1.png

Answer (score 3):

### Knife Project

If the vertices and box are two separate objects, great! If not, select one vertex of the edge loop, key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to *Select Linked*, key <kbd>P</kbd> to open the *Separate* menu, and select *By Selection*.

Move the loop away from the object on the *Y-Axis* a bit. Key <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> to enter *Orthographic View*. Key most likely either <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> (whatever view shows the loop in front of the box).

Select the edge loop, then the box, then key <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter *Edit Mode* for the box. Select the one face you wanted to add the vertices to, key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to *Select Inverse*, and key <kbd>H</kbd> to hide the other faces. Key <kbd>Space</kbd>, type **Knife Project**, and key <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Key <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to reveal the other faces.